# Lock down website with chmod 0000

Tags: wordpress, io, cpanel, cpu-usage, chmod

I am experiencing a many high CPU and I/O usage spikes and I want to find out what causes it. Under my main account I have 7 websites, all using WordPress. I want to lock down all websites except one to see if that website causes the high usages. The spikes are quite regular so I don't think it's visitor related. They are also there when there is hardly any visitor, at 3 am.

The webhost advised me to chmod 0000 the six website directories to stop access to the website. My question is: does it also stop the cronjob activity that came with the WP plugins and how about WebCalendar cronjobs that were set in CPanel? The WebCalendar is inside a directory that has a 0000 permission. Would there be any CPU and I/O usage when I lock it down like this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes chmod 0000 will stop the cron jobs, too.

Or you could just check the crontab.

Comment: Thanks, but this is all new to me. How can I check the crontab in CPanel?

Comment: Look under **Advanced** for **cronjobs**.

Comment: But how can I check there if cronjobs have run? Most I can do is to send an email automatically everytime I cron has fired, right?

Comment: You can see the time the jobs are scheduled to run in the crontab.

Comment: Btw, the high usage was all because of the Wordfence plugin. After I removed it everything was fine again